# CLion autocomplete for "std::cout << |cursor| << std::endl;"

Tags: autocomplete, clion

I would like to have a shortcut that writes `std::cout << |inserts cursor here| << std::endl;` for me.

In IntelliJ for example I can write `sout` and it gets auto completed to `System.out.println( |inserts cursor here| );`

When I write `cout` in CLion it just gets completed to `std::cout` with nothing else added.

It doesn't have to be a text shortcut, I am also content with a keypress shortcut or `shift + shift` action.

Comment: That sounds like a "Live Template" which you can add in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Some programmer dude's comment I just added this:

```
std::cout << $PRINT$ << std::endl;
$END$
```

to my **Clion live templates** with c++ application context.